# How to check recyclerview is empty or not in query addchildeventlistner

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am checking if firebase has data in it or not. If it has data then it should add in recyclerview otherwise a Toast message should show. But nothing is happening if database is empty means no Toast message is showing.
Please check my code for checking firebase has data or not.

```
  funnyJokesQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
               if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                   String contentdisplay = dataSnapshot.child("content").getValue(String.class);
                   ContentModel contentModel = new ContentModel(contentdisplay);
                   contentname.add(0, contentModel);
                   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   arrayAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
               } else if(!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                   progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   Toast.makeText(ContentActivity.this, "There is no jokes present under this category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
```

Nor Toast message is showing neither the progress bar's visibility is setting GONE.

Answer (score 0):

to check recyclerView is empty use following code:

```
 if (adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
         //called if recyclerview is empty
 } else {
         //called if recyclerview is not empty
 }
```

Comment: I should use this in onchildAdded method() na?